GraphQL file upload error: createReadStream is not a function
I'm working on a GraphQL server using Express and trying to upload files to AWS S3. I'm using the createReadStream function to handle file uploads, but I'm getting the following error:GraphQL Error: Error: File upload failed: createReadStream is not a function
My environment:
Node.js
Express
GraphQL without Apollo
AWS S3
Do I need to configure something specific to handle file uploads? If so, how can I correctly implement file upload handling in a GraphQL server without Apollo? Any advice would be appreciated!
Resolver Codes
const { uploadFile } = require("../../../../services/uploadFiles");
const { GraphQLUpload } = require('graphql-upload');
module.exports = {
   Upload: GraphQLUpload,
   Mutation: {
      discussionUploadFiles: async (_, { file }) => {
         try {
            const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype } = await file;
            console.log("filename", filename, "mimetype", mimetype)
            const fileUrl = await uploadFile(file);
            console.log(fileUrl)
            return fileUrl; // Return the uploaded file URL
         } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(`File upload failed: ${error.message}`);
         }
      }
   }
};


Schema Codes
const { gql } = require('graphql-tag');
module.exports = gql`
  scalar Upload
  type Mutation {
    discussionUploadFiles(file: Upload!): String!
  }
`;

App.js file
const express = require("express");
require("dotenv").config();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
const cors = require('cors');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { WebSocketServer } = require('ws');
const { useServer } = require('graphql-ws/lib/use/ws');
// Import multer for file uploads
const multer = require("multer");
const { graphqlUploadExpress } = require('graphql-upload');
// Import GraphQL schema
const schema = require("./graphql/schema/index");
// Import authentication middleware
const authenticate = require('./middleware/is-auth');

const app = express();
const mongoUri = process.env.db_credential;

if (!mongoUri) {
  console.error(`MongoURI was not supplied.`);
  process.exit(1); // Exit if MongoURI is not provided
}

// Connect to MongoDB with error handling
mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
  console.log("Connected to mongo instance");
});

mongoose.connection.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error("Error connecting to mongo", err);
});

// CORS configuration
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000', // Allow only the frontend origin
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
  credentials: true, // Enable credentials if you're using cookies or authentication
}));


// Configure multer
// const storage = multer.memoryStorage(); // Store files in memory
// const upload = multer({ storage });

// Body parser for handling JSON data in other routes (exclude /graphql)
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '10mb', extended: true }));
app.use(graphqlUploadExpress());
// GraphQL endpoint with authentication middleware
app.use("/graphql", (req, res, next) => {
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true,
    context: { user: req.user, req },
    customFormatErrorFn: (error) => {
      console.error('GraphQL Error:', error);
      return {
        message: error.message,
        locations: error.locations,
        stack: error.stack ? error.stack.split('\n') : [],
        path: error.path,
      };
    },
  })(req, res, next);
});


// Create an HTTP server with Express
const server = createServer(app);
// Initialize WebSocket server
const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
  server,
  path: '/graphql',
});

// Use graphql-ws to handle subscriptions
useServer({ schema }, wsServer);

wsServer.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('New WebSocket connection established');

  ws.on('message', (message) => {
    try {
      const parsedMessage = JSON.parse(message);
      console.log('Message received:', parsedMessage);

      if (parsedMessage.type === 'CONNECT') {
        console.log(`User connected: ${parsedMessage.userId}`);
        ws.userId = parsedMessage.userId;

        // Optionally, respond to the client to confirm the connection
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'CONNECTED', message: 'Connection established.' }));
      } else {
        console.log('Unknown message type');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error handling WebSocket message:', error);
    }
  });

  ws.on('close', (code, reason) => {
    console.log(`Connection closed: ${code} - ${reason}`);
  });

  ws.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
  });
});

console.log(`WebSocket server running on ws://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 4000}/graphql`);

// Error handling middleware for Express
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error('Unhandled error:', err);
  res.status(500).json({ error: 'An unexpected error occurred, but the server is still running.' });
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Yay! Backend works.`);
});

// Start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

module.exports = { wsServer };

package.json file
{
    "name": "noon-graphql",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js",
        "dev": "nodemon app.js"
    },
    "author": "mujib halimi",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "archiver": "^7.0.1",
        "aws-sdk": "^2.1685.0",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dataloader": "^1.4.0",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "express-graphql": "^0.12.0",
        "glob": "^7.2.3",
        "graphql": "^14.0.2",
        "graphql-tools": "^9.0.1",
        "graphql-upload": "^10.0.0",
        "graphql-ws": "^5.16.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
        "mongoose": "^5.13.17",
        "mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.0.13",
        "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
        "nodemon": "^3.0.2",
        "url": "^0.10.3",
        "vue-cli": "^2.9.6",
        "ws": "^8.18.0"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "18.x",
        "npm": "10.x"
    }
}

client.js file
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Function to download a file from a URL
const downloadFileFromUrl = async (url, outputPath) => {
   const writer = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath);
   const response = await axios({
      url,
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'stream',
   });
   response.data.pipe(writer);
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      writer.on('finish', resolve);
      writer.on('error', reject);
   });
};

// Function to upload file to a GraphQL endpoint
const uploadFileToGraphQL = async (filePath) => {
   const formData = new FormData();
   // Define the GraphQL mutation and variables
   formData.append('operations', JSON.stringify({
      query: `mutation($file: Upload!) { discussionUploadFiles(file: $file) }`,
      variables: {
         file: null,  // This will be mapped by the 'map' field
      }
   }));
   // Map the file in the form data
   formData.append('map', JSON.stringify({ '0': ['variables.file'] }));

   // Append the file stream
   formData.append('0', fs.createReadStream(filePath));

   // Make the request
   try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/graphql', formData, {
         headers: formData.getHeaders(),  // Important for setting proper headers
      });
      console.log('Response:', response.data);
   } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading file:', error.message);
   }
};

// Example usage
const fileUrl = 'https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/photorealistic-view-tree-nature-with-branches-trunk_23-2151478039.jpg';  // Replace with your file URL
const outputPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'downloads', 'sample.jpg');

// Download the file and upload it to the GraphQL server
downloadFileFromUrl(fileUrl, outputPath)
   .then(() => uploadFileToGraphQL(outputPath))
   .then(() => console.log('File uploaded successfully'))
   .catch((err) => console.error('Error', err.message));

I got this error in console

